# How To Change Visual Studio Code Tag And Label Font?

Tags: visual-studio-code, font-family

There are some parts of Visual Studio Code are using serif font, as illustrated below.
 
I want to change them into sans-serif font. I have checked all font options, but they haven't worked.
Could you help me to do it?
Thanks and cheers.

[image: Visual Studio Code Labels And Tags]

Comment: Is the `consolas` font installed on your machine?

Comment: Brother, Consolas font is installed and I could also change Editor and Console font by myself. The parts I mentioned is unaccessible in Settings menu, so I asked.